# JQuery Div Closing on click

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to insert html in a div using `$('#myDiv').show();` on a click of a checkbox.
But whenever I click somewhere in the Div that is not an object (Dropdownlist or a Textbox etc.) . The Div seems to be closing. Is there a property in Jquery to prevent this?.

```
    $(".mycheckboxDiv input[@type=checkbox]").click(
      function () {
        // Insert code here 
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                var y = $(this).attr('value');
                var divname = "reactiondiv" + y;
                $('#' + divname).show("1000");
                getData('ajaxService.asmx/GetControlHtml1', 'MyService/x/UserControls/SeverityandReactionWidget.ascx', divname, y, hiddendivname);
        }
    });
```

getData is a function that puts the HTML.  Which has the `$('#divName').html(eval(msg))` (I am using `$.ajax();`)

Comment: this should be because of another bug on your code, i dont see a reason for such behaviour.

Comment: could you post a small portion of actual html and jquery code

Comment: `.show()` does not insert html. For that you'd use `.html('...')`.

Comment: When you run this in firebug, do you get any errors reported? Do you have an onblur event handler that isn't shown?

Comment: the code you just posted doesn't even have myDiv.show()..could you please post all the code that relates to that and your div also

Comment: myDiv.show() is just an example. In the above example $('#' + divname).show("1000"); is the div